# A good alternative to Code::Blocks with wxWidgets for C++, I'm calling it Un-Installable

Tags: ide, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I'm kind of at the end of my rope.
Its day 4 of trying to install Code::Blocks 16.01 with wxWidgets 3.0.2 on a new Win 7 dev pc, with no success.
I have been using CB 13.12/wxW 3.0.2 on Win XP many years.  The XP pc is still operating, but its time to look forward.

Could someone suggest a (non-microsoft) RAD IDE that would be as nice as CB & wxW?  It doesn't have to be free.  QT is not a RAD, sadly.

I'm actually going to look for someone in the Midwest US (IL, MO) that I could pay hourly to assist in the installation of one or more Code::Block/wxWidget dev work stations.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: try CodeLite. Its free and written in wxWidgets

Comment: My fave is combination of Eclipse and wxFormBuilder. However, there is a little bit of copy paste from wxFormBuilder to Eclipse when designing a GUI.